# How to change String in Java

Tags: java, string

I want to change this string: "2014-03-24" to "140324" (yymmdd)
Anyone know how to delete first two chars and delete minus sign??
Thank You from the mountain

Comment: Look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  Use `.substring()` and `.replace()`.

Comment: You could find what you need pretty easily in the documentation for [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true).

Comment: Better yet here's some interesting material: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateintro.html ... if you are not or can not use Java 8...look into SimpleDateFormat class.

Comment: @JasonC This isn't a _constructive comment_.

Comment: Thank You guys i will search, by all what you wrote

Comment: @devnull You're right; I've been getting too moody with these types of questions.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `SimpleDateFormat`,

```
String str = "2014-03-24";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
str = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(str));
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two `SimpleDateFormat`s - one to `parse()` the first `String` into a `Date`, and the second to `format()` the resultant `Date` back into a String.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to do just simple String operations then use this-

```
String raw = "2014-03-24";
raw = raw.substring(2, raw.length()).replace("-", "");
System.out.println(raw);
```